# AttributeError while get text from html

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I don't know what happend, but the same code was still working two days ago!

What I try to do is to get the text with itemprop = "name", which is the title of the offered item. In this case: "Swatch".

```
import requests
import bs4
response2 = requests.get('https://www.willhaben.at/iad/kaufen-und-verkaufen/d/swatch-209522646/').content

soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response2, "lxml")

texttitle = soup2.find(itemprop = "name").get_text().strip()
print(texttitle)
```

How ever I always get the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`
Could anyone explain me why I get the AttributeError? Many thanks in advance.

Edit:

I also tried to locate it directly with the css path, but that didn't gave me any result.
By:

```
texttitle = soup2.find('div.adHeadingLine div.adHeading h1.header.cXenseParse').get_text().strip()
```

Comment: it is just `text()` not `get_text()`

Comment: Mostly because `soup2.find(itemprop = "name")` is actually returning None. You should print out the results of everything you are calling to see what you are actually getting back, and inspect deeper to see where the *real* problem lies. From there, you can determine what you should be doing to fix the problem.

Comment: Also text() gives the same error.

Comment: @fahrradlaus It is impossible to know who downvoted you, so it is best to never assume and try to call people out on it. Furthermore, regardless of which method is the correct one to be used here, you missed a few steps in your own troubleshooting. My previous comment provided a bit of context around that.

Comment: @idjaw Sorry I just didn't find it fair to get a downvote without any comment. Nevertheless, I tried some troubleshooting while locating the css path, but that didn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: @fahrradlaus Then provide a better [mcve] to explain what it is you are trying to achieve exactly? Your question right now is sitting in "why does this not work" territory, which is literally one of the off-topic close reasons. Please update your question to make it easier for readers to know what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @idjaw Is the edited question clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

Error that you get tells that there's no such element on the page.
Yesterday it could have been, but site's markup can change.

You can assure that an element, for which you give a condition, really exists:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

response = urlopen('https://www.willhaben.at/iad/kaufen-und-verkaufen/d/swatch-209522646/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")

if soup.find(itemprop='name'):
    texttitle = soup.find(itemprop='name').text.strip()
    print(texttitle)
else:
    print('no such element')
```

Comment: Many thanks, but in fact there is such an element on the site. Its located at the css path: `html body.frontend.page-object div#page-container div#page-container-inner div#page-content.clearfix div#box-maincontent.boxBlueRoundedCorners.bap div.wh-anzeige div.adHeadingLine div.adHeading h1.header.cXenseParse` So I'm wondering whether it has something to do with recent python updates I did....

Comment: What I'd do: look at the site's "view source code", not inspect. Find that element, look at its attributes, choose those, which will help you uniquely identify this element. And put this condition to your find()

Comment: This is basically exactly what I'm trying to do. The unique element is precisely the one I selected, still it gives me always an AttributeError. In this example, I'm just trying to fetch the title "Swatch".

Comment: I inspected this page a little. It seems that this title appears after page is loaded, some javascript is executed there.
Easy option not to hit your head against the wall is to use `seleium` library, which simulates browser and physically loads the page in pseudobrouser - webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting `None` back is because there is no element in that HTML page with a attribute called `itemprop` and its value set to `name`.

Looking at the source, there are definitely elements that use the `itemprop` attribute, such as:

```
<div itemprop='description' class="description">
    Batterie leer,ansonsten funktionsfähig!
</div>

<div itemprop='offers' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Offer' class="container right">
```

But there are no elements like `<div itemprop='name'>`, and that's why you're getting `None` back.

@dmitriy is correct in that the most likely reason is the website was updated.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But if I look at the website, there is such an element at `<h1 class="header cXenseParse" itemprop="name">Swatch</h1>`

Comment: As mentioned beneath it is located at the css path: `html body.frontend.page-object div#page-container div#page-container-inner div#page-content.clearfix div#box-maincontent.boxBlueRoundedCorners.bap div.wh-anzeige div.adHeadingLine div.adHeading h1.header.cXenseParse`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see that element in the HTML source. Perhaps you're looking at a different web page. Its very possible that the webserver is rendering different content based on the user (geolocation, etc). I recommend you share a link to the HTML source you're seeing (jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Alright, I tried to save it at jsfiddle.net. Never used it, but does it work like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ze6rj6y4/

Comment: That's not valid html. Save that as a .html file and open it in your browser, you'll find it does not render properly. Get the source (ctrl+u in Win/Chrome) and save the raw contents to a file.

Comment: Ok, now I finally got it. They added a script in Line 1487, which prevents from seeing the content! https://jsfiddle.net/2tydywwn/